# How can i update a table using the output from a inner join query performed on 2 other tables?

Tags: mysql

[1ST table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0g4p.png)

[2ND table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw5cL.png)

So the above two tables are the ones that I perform my inner join on and insert those values in a new table.
The values in the "detected" table gets updated through a face detection code, while the values in the table "students" is pre-fed

[DDL FOR TABLE 'students'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJJqH.png)

[DDL FOR TABLE 'detected'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro1vZ.png)

[DDL FOR TABLE 'tybscit3yr'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxTIB.png)

```
insert into bscit3yr
select students.ROLLNO, students.SNAME, detected.TIMING, detected.RDATE
from detected
inner join students on detected.SNAME = students.SNAME
where students.DEPARTMENT = "BSCIT" and students.ACADEMICYEAR = "TY"
```

The problem is I don't want duplicate values in my new table-"bscit3yr", since it runs the inner join query multiple times it shows me the error for duplicate entries

> mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2021505' for key 'ROLLNO_UNIQUE'.

This is the error that I get when the output of the inner join already exists in my "bscit3yr" table

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your tables DDL using `show create table youtable;`

Comment: Perhaps use 'INSERT IGNORE INTO bscit3yr SELECT ....'

Comment: i have added the DDL for the tables in the question @SelVazi

Comment: To do that you would need to first do a query on bscit3yr to identify what records have already been inserted, then feed that result back into your INSERT query to exclude those records from the SELECT.  That could be done via a temporary table, for instance

Comment: If you did go that route, probably best to wrap the whole thing in a transaction to avoid any conflicts that might occur due to changes happening between the two queries

Comment: both the solutions that I got work .....thank you for the immediate response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you can eliminate `ROLLNO` that are already in table `bscit3yr` :

```
insert into bscit3yr
select students.ROLLNO, students.SNAME, detected.TIMING, detected.RDATE
from detected
inner join students on detected.SNAME = students.SNAME
where students.DEPARTMENT = "BSCIT" and students.ACADEMICYEAR = "TY" 
and students.ROLLNO NOT IN (select ROLLNO from bscit3yr)
```

If you want to update the existing records you can use `REPLACE INTO`:

```
replace into bscit3yr
select students.ROLLNO, students.SNAME, detected.TIMING, detected.RDATE
from detected
inner join students on detected.SNAME = students.SNAME
where students.DEPARTMENT = "BSCIT" and students.ACADEMICYEAR = "TY"
```

`REPLACE` works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.